# How to distinguish boolean & integers after deserializing JSON?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsnumber

So, here's the problem:

1. __NSCFBoolean & __NSCFNumber are private
2. -[NSNumber boolValue] will cast 0/1 to NO/YES
3. It's not a question right now, that having false/true/0/1 as possible values in JSON is a bad idea
4. So how should one correctly distinguish between deserialized boolean & integer values?

Answer (score 2):

tldr: Use kCFBooleanFalse & kCFBooleanTrue to detect booleans correctly!

NSNumber holding booleans are instances of __NSCFBoolean private class, which is a special beast - pointer to any instance of this class will be either kCFBooleanFalse or kCFBooleanTrue, which gives us ability to use this code(ARC):

```
if ([value isKindOfClass::[NSNumber class]]) 
{
    if ((__bridge CFBooleanRef)value == kCFBooleanTrue) 
    {
        // value == @YES
    } 
    else if ((__bridge CFBooleanRef)value == kCFBooleanFalse) 
    {
        // value == @NO
    }
    else
    {
       // value is other type of number (int, float, etc...)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will probably work, however from code quality point of view it's a disaster.

Comment: I don't see why this is a disaster. if CF syntax scares you then you can do if(value == [NSNumber numblerWithBool:YES]) as it's exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple - don't.

Your data parser should know what value to expect on every place. Just don't mix numbers and booleans.

Comment: The problem is that it accepts a `1` and happily interprets it as BOOL. What if I want to accept `"is_supported": true`, but reject `"is_supported": 1` as a parse error?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no guarantee that you can determine the source type used to create an `NSNumber`. The `NSNumber` documentation states it is toll-free bridged with `CFNumber`, in other words an instance of one can be treated as an instance of the other (with appropriate bridge casts in the case of ARC). The documentation for both types clearly states that while the type of the value stored in an instance of either can be determined, by `CFNumberGetType()` or `objCType`, this may **not** be the same type as the instance was constructed with. This is from the `CFNumber` documentation:

> The type specified in the call to `CFNumberCreate` is not necessarily preserved when a new CFNumber object is created—it uses whatever internal storage type the creation function deems appropriate.

If you examine `CFNumberType`, an `enum` to represent the type of value in a `CFNumber`, then there is no value for `BOOL`.

Further there is the type `CFBoolean` to store wrapped booleans, it is not defined as a subtype of `CFNumber` or mentioned in the documentation for either it or `NSNumber`.

While it transpires that *currently* if you create an `NSNumber` with a `BOOL` value the result has been observed to be one of the constant values defined by `CFBoolean` there is no documentation that states that this is the defined behaviour.

So while for curiosity sake you can try to figure it out, don't rely on any specific behaviour in production code.

*Note:* `CFBoolean` is defined as one of the Core Foundation property list types. It may be possible to prove through using the various toll-free bridge relationships etc. that a `CFBoolean` must be toll-free bridged to `NSNumber`. However I do not think that guarantees to you that a boolean from JSON must be a `CFBoolean` instance, though it *probably is*...

Comment: A good example of this lack of guarantee is with NSManagedObject, if you set a NSNumber that identifies as a boolean either as equal to kCFBooleanTrue kCFBooleanFalse, when you get it back again its now just a generic NSNumber that can't be identified as a boolean. Really annoying when it comes to serialising an NSManagedObject to JSON because you are stuck with a 1 or a 0 unless you do inspection of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with another solution:

```
id value_from_json = json[key];
if([value_from_json isKindOfClass[NSNumber class]]) {
    NSNumber *number_value = (NSNumber *)value_from_json;
    // Observe that the check is "isEqualToValue", not "isEqualToNumber"
    if([number_value isEqualToValue:@YES] || [number_value isEqualToValue:@NO]) {
        // It's a boolean
    } else {
        // It's not a boolean
    }
}
```

I have tested it and it can distingush between "true", true and 1. (and "false", false and 0)